# Mutate new column with values conditioned by other columns of the dataset

Tags: dplyr, mutate

The goal of this question is how to create a column with values that depend on the maximum value of other columns that can be grouped.

I have a dataset with the tree species proportions of some plots for 4 years. I would like to extract which is the dominant species in each plot at each year.

It is possible to create a test dataset by running these lines:

```
jobFun <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(runif(3*n,0,1), ncol=3)
  m<- sweep(m, 1, rowSums(m), FUN="/")
  m
}

year1 = data.frame(jobFun(10))
colnames(year1) = paste0("Year1_", c("Spruce", "Pine", "Birch"))

year2 = data.frame(jobFun(10))
colnames(year2) = paste0("Year2_", c("Spruce", "Pine", "Birch"))

year3 = data.frame(jobFun(10))
colnames(year3) = paste0("Year3_", c("Spruce", "Pine", "Birch"))

year4 = data.frame(jobFun(10))
colnames(year4) = paste0("Year4_", c("Spruce", "Pine", "Birch"))

df = cbind(year1, year2, year3, year4)
```

I can make a loop for each of the years and compare the values, but is not very clean and I would like to learn more about `mutate` commands and `dplyr`. For example, for year 1:

```
# Dominant Species in year 1
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(which.max(select(df[i,],c("Year1_Spruce","Year1_Pine","Year1_Birch"))) == 1){
    df$dom.species.y1[i] <- "S"
  } else if(which.max(select(df[i,],c("Year1_Spruce","Year1_Pine","Year1_Birch"))) == 2){
    df$dom.species.y1[i] <- "P"
  }else{
    df$dom.species.y1[i] <- "D"
  }
}
```

```
> df$dom.species.y1
 [1] "S" "P" "P" "S" "S" "P" "D" "P" "D" "S"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating test data set, I would set the random seed for reproducibility

```r
set.seed(42)
```

The key to using `dplyr` (and the rest of the `tidyverse`) is first having your data in a [tidy format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), part of which is every variable in a separate column. It appears the three variables are year, species, and plot id (represented by each row). This can be accomplished with `tidyr`.

```
tidyDf <- df |> 
  tibble::rowid_to_column("plot_id") |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Year"),
    names_to = c("year", "species"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) 
#> # A tibble: 120 × 4
#>    plot_id year  species  value
#>      <int> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1       1 Year1 Spruce  0.402 
#>  2       1 Year1 Pine    0.201 
#>  3       1 Year1 Birch   0.397 
#>  4       1 Year2 Spruce  0.508 
#>  5       1 Year2 Pine    0.262 
#>  6       1 Year2 Birch   0.230 
#>  7       1 Year3 Spruce  0.520 
#>  8       1 Year3 Pine    0.0331
#>  9       1 Year3 Birch   0.447 
#> 10       1 Year4 Spruce  0.351 
#> # … with 110 more rows
```

Once it's in a tidy format, you can group by the variables of interest and summarize  using the helper function `first` to select where value is max for each group (`-value` is tidy syntax for descending order).

```
domSpeciesByYear <- tidyDf |> 
  dplyr::group_by(plot_id, year) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(
    dom_species = dplyr::first(species, order_by = -value), 
    .groups = "drop"
  ) 
#> # A tibble: 40 × 3
#>    plot_id year  dom_species
#>      <int> <chr> <chr>      
#>  1       1 Year1 Spruce     
#>  2       1 Year2 Spruce     
#>  3       1 Year3 Spruce     
#>  4       1 Year4 Spruce     
#>  5       2 Year1 Spruce     
#>  6       2 Year2 Spruce     
#>  7       2 Year3 Spruce     
#>  8       2 Year4 Birch      
#>  9       3 Year1 Birch      
#> 10       3 Year2 Birch      
#> # … with 30 more rows
```

This essentially solves the question about which species is dominant in each plot in each year, but you can pivot back if you want it in the exact format from the question.

```
domSpeciesByYear |> 
  dplyr::mutate(dom_species = stringr::str_sub(dom_species, start = 1, end = 1)) |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols = plot_id,
    names_from = year,
    names_glue = "dom.species.y{stringr::str_sub(year, start = -1)}",
    values_from = dom_species
  ) |> 
  dplyr::select(-plot_id) 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    dom.species.y1 dom.species.y2 dom.species.y3 dom.species.y4
#>    <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
#>  1 S              S              S              S             
#>  2 S              S              S              B             
#>  3 B              B              S              B             
#>  4 B              P              B              S             
#>  5 S              P              S              P             
#>  6 P              P              P              P             
#>  7 P              P              S              P             
#>  8 B              P              S              P             
#>  9 S              P              S              S             
#> 10 B              P              B              B
```

Comment: Amazing how you play with the data. I really need to get my head around dplyr. Why is it neccesary to set the random seed for reproducibility?

Comment: The call to `runif` will return different values otherwise every time you call `jobFun` and there will be a different `df$dom.species.y1`. I just added it so you can see if you get the same answer as I did. I assume your actual data isn't random so `set.seed` is only needed for this test example.